# How to interpret coefficients of angular terms in a regression model?

Tags: regression, interpretation, circular-statistics

Given the model $$Y = a + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 \cos(\angle) + \beta_4 \sin(\angle) + \text{ errors}$$ resulting from a negative binomial regression, how can I explain the $\beta_3 \cos((\angle) + \beta_4 \sin(\angle)$ terms given that they are the two predictors emerging from the angle of inclination $\angle$ (a variable measured in the raw dataset)?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Gsenka. It's not clear to me what you are asking - please can you give a bit more detail about what you are trying to achieve and what it is that you don't understand/are struggling to interpret? Are you really fitting three constants (a, β1 and β2), and if so why?

Comment: You have previously been pointed to an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148472/212689) (and further linked information) by Nick Cox. If you are struggling with the concepts in that, please clarify what it is that you need help to understand.

Comment: If you are struggling to understand how to interpret a regression where you have two terms reliant on the value of a single explanatory variable ((∠) in your case), try taking a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/409329/212689) post.

Answer (score 4):

**The question is a good one: when including an angular variable $w$ among the explanatory variables in any regression model by incorporating its sine and cosine, how does one interpret the two estimated coefficients?**

Let's write this mathematically just to make things perfectly clear.  Suppose you model a response $Y$ in the form

$$Y = X\beta + \alpha_1 \cos(w) + \alpha_2 \sin(w) + \text{ random error}$$

and (somehow) you estimate the parameters as $b, a_1, a_2$ to obtain the *fit*

$$\hat Y(X,w) = Xb + a_1 \cos(w) + a_2\sin(w) + \text{ residuals}.$$

**What do the $a_i$ *mean* when you're interested in the relationship between $w$ and $Y$?**

Typically, we express such relationships *differentially* by stating what happens to $\hat Y$ when (hypothetically) the value of $w$ is changed a tiny bit, say to $w+\delta$ for a small angle $\delta.$  We can work this out trigonometrically.  Note that all the change occurs in just the two angular terms of the model ($Xb$ is not involved), so let's focus on how the angular terms differ.

When angles are expressed in radians we may feel free to treat $\sin(\delta)$ as approximately $\delta$ and $\cos(\delta)$ as approximately equal to $1,$ because the relative error made in either instance is proportional to $\delta^2,$ which is truly tiny.  Trigonometry tells us that

$$\cos(w+\delta) - \cos(w) = \cos(w)\cos(\delta) - \sin(w)\sin(\delta) - \cos(w)  \approx - \sin(w)\delta$$

and

$$\sin(w+\delta) - \sin(w)=\sin(w)\cos(\delta) + \cos(w)\sin(\delta) - \sin(w) \approx  \cos(w)\delta.$$

> Consequently the difference in the fit induced by changing the angle $w$ by a small amount of $\delta$ radians is $$\hat Y(X,w+\delta) - \hat Y(X,w) \approx (-a_1\sin(w) + a_2\cos(w))\,\delta.$$

**To interpret this further,** it's handy to re-express the $a_i$ in polar coordinates where $a_1 = r\cos(\phi)$ and $a_2=r\sin(\phi)$ for some non-negative number $r$ and angle $\phi.$  This can always be done by taking $r = \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}$ and then computing $\phi$ as the arctangent of the vector $(a_1, a_2)$ or, equivalently, as the argument of the complex number $a_1 + a_2\mathbf{i}.$  The change in response can now be expressed as

$$\hat Y(X,w+\delta) - \hat Y(X,w) \approx (-a_1\sin(w) + a_2\cos(w))\ \delta = -\sin(w-\phi)\, r \ \delta.$$

(When measuring in degrees, multiply $\delta$ by $180/\pi \approx 57.3.$)

If that sine term weren't there, we would be looking at a traditional expression: the change $r\delta$ in $\hat Y$ is $r$ times the change in $w.$  This is modified by the sine term, though, but it's not difficult to understand: it is zero when $w=\phi,$ increases to $1$ when $w$ is 90 degrees clockwise of $\phi$ ($w=\phi+\pi/2$), returns to $0$ when $w$ is directly opposite $\phi$ ($w=\phi+\pi$), decreases to $-1$ when $w$ is 90 degrees counterclockwise of $\phi$ ($w=\phi + 3\pi/2$), and finally returns to $0.$

Thus, **$\phi$ is a kind of *origin* of the angular effect:** when $w=\pm \phi,$ a little change in $w$ doesn't appreciably change the response, whereas otherwise the change depends on how far away from the origin $w$ is, swinging back and forth between $-r$ and $r.$

We can summarize this simply:

> A small change in the angle $w$ changes the fit $\hat Y$ by an amount between $-r$ and $r,$ where $r^2 = a_1^2 + a_2^2$ and the change is measured in radians.  That amount depends on where $w$ is situated relative to the angle made by the vector $(a_1, a_2)$ in the plane counterclockwise of the vector $(1,0)$ (that is, "north of east" in geographers' terms).